# how many cubes have at least $1,2,3$ colors on them

Tags: combinations, puzzle

I have a painted cube, which is cut into $n^3$ smaller cubes. I now want to find the number of cubes which have $1$,$2$,$3$ sides painted. I know the long way round of taking each cube and putting them into different categories... but is there a short way or formula to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$1$ face painted - You have to consider all the faces. There are $6$ faces, each with $(n-2)^2$ cubes with $1$ face painted . That gives you the formula $$6*(n-2)^2$$

$2$ faces painted - You have to take the edges. There are $12$ edges, each edge having $n-2$ cubes with $2$ faces painted . That gives you the formula $$12*(n-2)$$

$3$ faces painted - You have to take the corners alone. That gives you the formula $$8$$

Extra - $0$ faces painted - You have to consider the interior alone which gives $$(n-2)^3$$

Comment: I think that you want $8$ corners.  ;-)

Comment: @SammyBlack Thank you for that. Edited.

Comment: saying side is not corrrect it is face which is painted

Comment: @Bhaskara-III The question asked for *side*, hence, I used *side*.

Comment: oops you should have correctly mentioned that it should be a painted face not a painted side in your answer because it's very confusing term

Comment: @Bhaskara-III  Well, I didn't think it would matter much.., I edited nevertheless.

Comment: yeah, it's noww clear

Answer (score 2):

This is an addendum to Win Vineeth's excellent answer:  the particular counts fall out of the algebraic expansion (using the [Binomial Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem)) of $n^3$, where we write $n = (n-2) + 2$:
$$
\bigl( (n-2) + 2 \bigr)^3 = (n-2)^3 + 6(n-2)^2 + 12(n-2) + 8
$$

This approach generalizes by letting $t$ be the "thickness" of the boundary (the part that gets painted).  The original question uses $t=1$.  The expansion now looks like:
$$
\bigl( (n-2t) + 2t \bigr)^3 = (n-2t)^3 + 6(n-2t)^2t + 12(n-2t)t^2 + 8t^3
$$
Now, the power of $t$ serves as a placeholder for the number of sides that got painted.  For example, if you want to know how many subcubes got painted on $2$ sides, then look at the coefficient of $t^2$, namely $12(n-2t)$, which is $12(n-2)$ once you set $t=1$.  This is an example of a [generating function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function), where a sequence is encoded as the list of coefficients of a polynomial (or often infinite series).

This approach also has the advantage of counting the number of boundary subhypercubes of a hypercube of *any* dimension:  just expand $n^d$, where $d$ is the dimension.